# Geofencing radius distribution/ratio across multiple geofences

Tags: python, shapefile, r, polygon, geofencing

I understand that this problem might be simple geometry, but Im using specific shapefiles for a geographical area and looking for a specific gis solution (hopefully code).

[image]

Essentially Id like to find the area of black that covers each separate geographical bounds. What percentage covers the red area, blue area, and then green?

I have coordinates of the center, as well as shapefiles (.shp). The radius is known. No preference on library other than it being open source (R and Python).

Comment: Have you this topic [Percentage of overlap between polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694530/percentage-of-overlap-between-polygons)? R solution

Comment: This is an intersect operation. First use rgeos::gBuffer to create polygon representing your radius then raster::intersect to intersect the buffer polygon with the other boundary polygons. The new feature will represent the shared overlap. You can then get the area of each polygon using rgeos::gArea

Comment: ..or use the `sf` package and functions like `st_intersection`. Read an intro to spatial data or take an online course for more.